# Page won't always load when using asp-prerender-module, unless solution is cleaned

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, react-redux

I'm simply trying to get the React/Redux template in visual studio to work without issues however one strange issue I run into is with the **asp-prerender-module**

If I run a freshly cleaned and rebuilt project I rarely run into issues loading the website. And the output on the console is below:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\User\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1
Now listening on: http://localhost:65368
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:65368/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Index (WebApplication1) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      webpack built d0f7a90d984ff68a1745 in 10926ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Index (WebApplication1) in 9120.0386ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 10844.7069ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:65368/dist/site.css?v=Lb5HSsGvBcEgLMQZ61Nva-Lpee8TNSEJ0mFBnX5PmbQ
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:65368/dist/main-client.js?v=hs7AcDOPK7Fl3jp2TqGfNBpg_ZXXwsOVJEdhINfjU6k
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 83.3469ms 200 text/css; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 50.5045ms 200 application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:65368/dist/__webpack_hmr
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:65368/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Index (WebApplication1) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Index (WebApplication1) in 3428.5329ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 3460.171ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:65368/dist/site.css?v=Lb5HSsGvBcEgLMQZ61Nva-Lpee8TNSEJ0mFBnX5PmbQ
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:65368/dist/main-client.js?v=hs7AcDOPK7Fl3jp2TqGfNBpg_ZXXwsOVJEdhINfjU6k
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 153.7767ms 200 text/css; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 536.5599ms 200 application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:65368/dist/__webpack_hmr
```

And the page looks like this:
[image: Working Page]

However if I just restart the project:

[image: VS restart]

The console only displays this:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
```

Then times out after 60 seconds throwing an exception and stopping the project:

```
Application startup exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms.
) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms.

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.<InvokeExportAsync>
    d__13`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>
        d__10`1.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>
            d__10`1.MoveNext()
            --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebpackDevMiddleware.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder, WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions options)
            at WebApplication1.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Startup.cs:line 34
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup.ApplicationInsightsLoggerStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>
                b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
                at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>
                    b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
                    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>
                        b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
                        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
                        ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms.

                        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.<InvokeExportAsync>
                            d__13`1.MoveNext()
                            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
                            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>
                                d__10`1.MoveNext()
                                --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>
                                    d__10`1.MoveNext()<--- crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
                                                           Application startup exception
                                                           System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms.
                                                           ) --->
                                        Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms.

                                        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.<InvokeExportAsync>
                                            d__13`1.MoveNext()
                                            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
                                            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>
                                                d__10`1.MoveNext()
                                                --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>
                                                    d__10`1.MoveNext()
                                                    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                                                    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
                                                    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebpackDevMiddleware.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder, WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions options)
                                                    at WebApplication1.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Startup.cs:line 34
                                                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
                                                    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup.ApplicationInsightsLoggerStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>
                                                        b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
                                                        at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>
                                                            b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
                                                            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>
                                                                b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
                                                                at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
                                                                ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms.

                                                                at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.<InvokeExportAsync>
                                                                    d__13`1.MoveNext()
                                                                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                                    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                                                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
                                                                    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>
                                                                        d__10`1.MoveNext()
                                                                        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                                        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                                        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()<---
```

A lot of times it gets this far:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\User\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1
Now listening on: http://localhost:65368
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:65368/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      webpack built d0f7a90d984ff68a1745 in 10640ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Index (WebApplication1) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.
```

But then Fails:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\User\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1
Now listening on: http://localhost:65368
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:65368/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      webpack built d0f7a90d984ff68a1745 in 10640ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Index (WebApplication1) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Index (WebApplication1) in 64664.3951ms
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms.

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.<InvokeExportAsync>
    d__13`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>
        d__10`1.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>
            d__10`1.MoveNext()
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering.PrerenderTagHelper.<ProcessAsync>
                d__29.MoveNext()
                --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>
                    d__0.MoveNext()
                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                    at AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml.<ExecuteAsync>
                        d__12.MoveNext() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line 2
                        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.<RenderPageCoreAsync>
                            d__16.MoveNext()
                            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.<RenderPageAsync>
                                d__15.MoveNext()
                                --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
                                at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.<RenderAsync>
                                    d__14.MoveNext()
                                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>
                                        d__22.MoveNext()
                                        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>
                                            d__21.MoveNext()
                                            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>
                                                d__26.MoveNext()
                                                --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                                at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>
                                                    d__19.MoveNext()
                                                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                                    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>
                                                        d__24.MoveNext()
                                                        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
                                                        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
                                                        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>
                                                            d__22.MoveNext()
                                                            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
                                                            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
                                                            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>
                                                                d__17.MoveNext()
                                                                --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                                at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                                                at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>
                                                                    d__15.MoveNext()
                                                                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                                    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                                                    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>
                                                                        d__4.MoveNext()
                                                                        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                                        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                                        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                                                        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.<Invoke>
                                                                            d__6.MoveNext()
                                                                            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                                            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                                            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                                                            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.<Invoke>
                                                                                d__6.MoveNext()
                                                                                --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                                                                at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                                                                at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                                                                                at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>
                                                                                    d__7.MoveNext()
                                                                                    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
                                                                                    Request finished in 70042.4099ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Showing a page like this:

[image]

But then refreshing the page fixes the problem. I haven't really done React/Redux before so I'm trying to the example works properly. I know removing **asp-prerender-module** will have the page load each time but that feels like avoiding the issue.